# Is it possible to include tags from one XML file in other vector drawable XML file?

Tags: android

I realized that my drawable XML files (vectors and animated vectors) have a lot of common tags and I was wondering if it would be possible to optimize the size of my resources using some `<include/>` like tags.

I know that Android allows to use such tag with layouts using syntax

```
<include layout="@layout/resource_name"/>
```

but I am not sure if there is a similar option for drawable files. Or is there some other way how to reuse same parts of XML files in vector drawables?

Comment: you want to `include`a drawable/layout within a vector drawable ??

Comment: @SantanuSur - I want to include and re-use `<group>`, `<path>`, `<target>`, `<objectAnimator>`, and other similar tags that are present in multiple drawable files.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using `<aapt:attr>` are you? Because this is a preprocessing tool to generate separate files, and you could just as easily make separate files yourself and thus gain that reusability you seek.

Instead of:

`allInOne.xml`

```
<animated-vector ... >
    <aapt:attr name="android:drawable">
        <vector ...>
            ...
        </vector>
    </aapt:attr>
    <target ... >
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <objectAnimator ... />
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
</animated-vector>
```

You can have:

`animated.xml`

```
<animated-vector ... android:drawable="@drawable/vector">
    <target ... android:animation="@animator/animator" />
</animated-vector>
```

`vector.xml`

```
<vector ...>
    ...
</vector>
```

`animator.xml`

```
<objectAnimator ... />
```

Beyond that, I suppose you could take apart your vector drawables and then re-compose them using `<layer-list>` or by other means. What you can't do is use `<include>`.